# Android Studio says 'Local variable is redundant'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, refactoring

I am getting a warning on many methods that `local variable is redundant`.

Here is a sample method:

```
public MyObject getMSListItem(int pos) {
    MyObject li = getItem(pos);
    return li;
}
```

Now it SEEMS, I suppose, I can do this to fix it:

```
public MyObject getMSListItem(int pos) {
    return  getItem(pos);
}
```

Another example:

```
public String getTeacher(int pos) {
    ffTeacherListItem t = getItem(pos);
    String teacher = t.teacher;
    return teacher;
}
```

Seems this could be:

```
public String getTeacher(int pos) {
    ffTeacherListItem t = getItem(pos);
    return t.teacher;
}
```

OR as recommended below, even better!

```
public String getTeacher(int pos) {
    return  getItem(pos).teacher;
}
```

Is there really a "best practice" for this? Is one way better than the other? Or is it just about code readability and nothing more?

Comment: Well, your IDE certainly thinks it's a good practice :)

Comment: `return getItem(pos).teacher`

Comment: Yes, and the way it tells you to be is correct. There is no reason to create a copy of something when you can just return that instance.

Comment: @zgc7009: it is not a copy. It is merely a named reference, instead of having an anonymous reference.

Comment: the redundancy removal is only cosmetic. It does not change anything to your code. But less lines is always good when there is no complexity added.

Comment: Also, it prevent having temporary variables with senseless names. `t` or `li` does not say anything about what this object is doing (which makes sense since it's not doing anything.)

Comment: @njzk2  I think that best answers this question.  Nothing is changed in the end outside of cleaner code.

Comment: @njzk2 that is good to know, I must have misunderstood that in learning java. I thought that MyObject li = getItem(pos) made a copy of the referenced object while if li had already been previously created it would be a named reference.

Comment: Removing the redundant local variable is a "best practice" due to better readability. It is not either-or as your question suggests.

Comment: I think my confusion, and @njkz2 maybe you can help on this, is that the named reference variable will need to be instantiated if it is passed as a variable to a method. That is what allows values passed to methods to be modified in memory. No?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there really a "best practice" for this? Is one way better than the
>   other? Or is it just about code readability and nothing more?

Simplified said: **In your scenario** it's useless. It's not incorrect but why you would you do this:

```
ffTeacherListItem t = getItem(pos);
String teacher = t.teacher;
return teacher;
```

when you can do same thing with:

```
ffTeacherListItem t = getItem(pos);
return t.teacher;
```

or also you can do:

```
return getItem(pos).teacher;
```

All above do same but second and third code is cleaner and you should always try to write clean code without useless lines and references<sup>1</sup>. There is also unwritten rule - *Less code, less errors*.

<sup>1</sup><sub>This is "advantage" of languages like C++ which don't have garbage collector and you are responsible for all objects and instances you'll create (their releasing from memory etc.). So you are thinking more before you'll decide to create new instance of some Object.</sub>

Comment: But, beware. If you're chaining multiple method calls, like `getItem().getTeacher().getClass().getStudents()`, and this line throws a `NullPointerException`, you have no idea which of the three returned `null`.

Comment: The problem goes further than just NPE. You get zero visibility into the code execution for future debugging. Declaring variables gives you something to look at if and when something goes wrong. Otherwise you have to double evaluate a function with a watch. Since we're in Java, this means possible side effects, which means possibly confusing things that make Debugging even harder!